# How to crop the four corners of the image like rounded rectangle(vertical) after merge the two images?

Tags: image, ios7, merge, rounded-corners, xcode5.1

I am struggling with cropping the image corners.

I want to merge two images with different shapes like one is with square shape and another one is with vertical rounded rectangle shape.

I merged the two images and blend them one on another. But I am unable to crop the square image into vertical rounded rectangle shape.

Please give me the idea how I have to crop the image corners.......

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
[myImageView.layer setCornerRadius:2.0f]; // adjust 2.0 as per your need
```